# Span tag onclick loads blank page?

Tags: javascript

I've got a span tag:

```
<span id="myBtnfb"
    class="demo" onclick="open()">
    <span class="icon">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="">Testing</span>
</span>
```

and some javascript

```
  function open() {
      alert('Hello');
  }
```

Now, what I want to happen is when the span is clicked, it fires the function "open".   What seems to happen though is it just reloads the page but brings back a blank page.  Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/qtf5s/

Comment: Your fiddle is set to run `onLoad` - change it to run not wrapped in `<head>` (so it is exposed globally) and change the name of the function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`open()` is a native JavaScript function, which opens a new page (in this case blank since there's no params specified): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Just rename your function to something like `openAlert()`: http://jsfiddle.net/qtf5s/2/.

Also, @Ian mentioned in the comments that in JSFiddle, it's best to change the JavaScript wrap to "No wrap - in " so that the code works.

Comment: That's not the only problem - the fiddle runs `onLoad`, so whatever function they create won't be globally available (to the inline event handler)

Comment: @Ian That's JSFiddle's problem (I had to change the settings of my fiddle to "No wrap - in <body>"

Comment: That's the OP's/your problem, not jsFiddle's. If you're going to suggest a solution, you should mention all problems

Comment: @Ian But I wouldn't think that is a problem - the JSFiddle is simply for demonstrating the code. I don't think the OP uses `onLoad` in his original code... I recognize his fiddle's settings are wrong, but is that really the problem? Thanks for you suggestion/comment though, appreciated.

Comment: @AlfredXing What all did you have to change in the fiddle? You changed the function name (which undoubtedly is the problem in any context), and you changed the fiddle setting...so why wouldn't you explain both problems? If you only changed the function name, it wouldn't work. Too many people use jsFiddle and come up with these problems because they don't know how to use the settings on the left (which is bad). Of course, a lot of things can be avoided if they just use best practices in the first place - no inline event handlers (so the functions don't need to be global)

Comment: @Ian I didn't explain the fiddle because there's no real need: I say "change the function name", the OP changes it in the original code, and it works fine. The OP isn't working in JSFiddle. This is my thought because the OP added the fiddle link as an edit (it wasn't there originally), so I know that he's not actually using fiddle.

In addition, this is the type of question in which the mis-set fiddle still illustrates the problem: in the OP's fiddle, if you click the span, the frame goes blank as in the question.

But seeing as you're pretty persistent, I've edited my answer :)

Comment: @AlfredXing I see what you're saying. I guess I just meant it wouldn't hurt to include the explanation of why it's now working in your **demo** - **both** the function name change **and** the fiddle setting. You're absolutely right that the OP (hopefully) wouldn't have the same problem in their own code due to the fiddle setting, but I would've explained anything I changed, whether it truly applies to them or not. Either way, it's probably unnecessary by now, and maybe even unnecessary in the first place :) Your answer's obviously right, I was just trying to explain more for the OP